# One redis channel per user?

Tags: redis, socket.io

I was trying to understand this socket.io code which uses Gevent and Redis pub/sub. Apparently the `subscribe` method waits for a message on a channel.

Can I have (tens of) thousands of channels, one channel **each** for pushing notifications and chats to one user? Are channels meant for that?

```
def _sub_listener(socketio, chan):
    """
    This is the method that will block and listen
    for new messages to be published to redis, since
    we are using coroutines this method can block on
    listen() without interrupting the rest of the site
    """
        red = Redis(REDIS_HOST)
        red.subscribe(chan)

        for i in red.listen():
            socketio.send({'message': i})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for the same thing. Through searching I found forums that says Redis can handle upto 10k channels very efficiently. But I have not got any absolute answers on what happens if the channel exceeds 10k.

I'm currently trying to go ahead with shared channel.
[Here](https://gist.github.com/josiahcarlson/1045789) is a sample algorithm/implementation that uses shared channel.